# What's the cleanest way to transfer WordPress to a new server

Tags: database, backup

I manage a website with more than 6k posts, and I'm having some server issues, so I'm planning to transfer it to a new server, but I want to do the best not to bring the issues with it.

1. What's the cleanest method to transfer a wordpress site?
2. If I create a database backup, there's a chance of bringing some mysql (e.g., queries) or data issues?

Comment: Have you read https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/?

Comment: Yes, I read it. I was asking more for other people experiences and how they handle transfers with cleanly.